# OperationalError: could not connect to server: Permission denied tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: linux, django, postgresql

I can able to connect postgres from terminal as well as python manage.py dbshell command

But when i'm trying to connect from apache i'm Getting error as follows.

```
Error : OperationalError: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running on host "192.168.1.10" and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My listen Address on postgress conf file is 192.168.1.10 Address

pg_hg_cong allowed host all all 192.168.0.0/24 trust

And also selinux turned httpd_can_network_connect_db on

Port is listening on 192.168.1.10:5432 on netstat output.

And database's are storing in /tmp directory

```
wxrwxrwx.  1 postgres postgres     0 Dec 18 07:40 .s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres    50 Dec 18 07:40 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

Comment: Try telnetting to 192.168.1.10 port 5432. If that doesn't work, Django will also not be able to connect so the problem is elsewhere. Try disabling your firewall etc.

Comment: I can able to connect using telnet and also with django with following command python manage.py dbshell

Comment: Perhaps `pg_hg_cong allowed host all all 192.168.0.0/24 trust` -->> `pg_hg_cong allowed host all all 192.168.0.0/16 trust` BTW: normally you would set the listen address to `*` (all available interfaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have enabled selinux httpd_can_network_connect_db parameters on db server instead of web server

So issue got solved after enabling httpd_can_network_connect_db on web server